# Eclipse fresh install doesn't start up

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu-14.04

I installed eclipse mars on my new workstation, it is failing to startup. During startup I get these logs after which the eclipse window becomes blank.

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/sselvaraj/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.6.2.20150902-0002.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://472.fwk1268650975:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://472.fwk1268650975:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and Oracle Java8. Any idea why eclipse fails?

The workspace that I am creating is also a new directory.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is related. Do you have a complete log file?

Comment: I could be bug. Please check this [https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436002](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436002)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I did the following and it worked:

1. put `--launcher.GTK_version 2` before `--launcher.defaultAction openFile`  in eclipse.ini
2. put `-vm path_of_java($JAVA_HOME/bin/java)` after `--launcher.defaultAction openFile` in eclipse.ini

It worked for me, hopefully will help you too.

Comment: this did not work for me. Same error. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04